# Error during running face detection program OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am running a face detection program on python and I am runnning into this error below and couldn't figure out whats wrong. Please help.

```
import cv2

face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

img=cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Maxy\\PycharmProjects\\Learn Python\\denzel.jpg", 1)

gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=5)

print(type(faces))
print(faces)

for x,y,w,h in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow("Gray", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxy\PycharmProjects\Learn Python\OpenCV3.py", line 13, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, 1.05, 5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: please check shape of gray image it looks like there is no image. Verify path. [Follow these path practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python).

Comment: the casccade was not loaded (wrong path)